# How to run Putty session with Plink from VBA macro

Tags: ssh, vba, putty, macros

I am trying to automate an ssh session by starting a putty session using plink.exe from a VBA macro. Part of the automation is sending some commands to a linux server. After I run the macro; plink opens in a blank command prompt window but closes a few seconds later .  This is the line that attempts to run plink.exe `Set oExec = WshShell.exec("plink.exe -load aaTest")`. I suspected originally that it might be improper string formatting.  However, when I try to run the putty gui from the same macro by replacing the above line with `Set oExec = WshShell.exec("putty.exe -load aaTest")`, the putty gui opens and I can login. The StdIn.Write code doesn't work and that is because putty doesn't use StdIn.  But I don't get why plink isn't working. What am I doing wrong here?

Full macro is below.

```
Sub AutoMop()
'
' AutoMop Macro
'
'
Set WshShell = VBA.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.CurrentDirectory = ("C:\Users\lxp\Core\91CS\PuTTY")
Set oExec = WshShell.exec("plink.exe -load aaTest")

' Write to the input stream
oExec.StdIn.Write "service ssh status" & vbCrLf
'Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:00:05"))
oExec.StdIn.Write "sudo service ssh restart" & vbCrLf
End Sub
```

Comment: So did you try capturing plink output? Or enabling logging? Imo, this question would better fit on [so].

Comment: Logging is enabled through the saved session in putty.  When running the macro no log entries are made to the log file. However when I run plink from the command line it does.

Comment: So did you try capturing plink output?

Comment: I'm not familiar with how to accomplish that. What tool should I use for this?

Comment: Read `oExec.StdOut`?